# show users doesn't show anything, although it has users

Tags: mongodb, nosql

So I'm using MongoDB, and this is my first time dealing with a VPS on my own, I'm trying to view the users i have on the website. I know for a fact that there are signed up users, because I can signup & Login and it all works.

I Also tried to connect to the database from MongoDB Compass but failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I thought you are talking about MongoDB users. So, I had to change my answer.

You can try the below command for seeing to the collection which is `users`

```
db.users.find({})
```

Comment: yes that worked perfectly, thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a few to the `Yunus's answer` , here are some other queries to find the users

1. Get users command , its similar to show users

> `db.getUsers()`

You can also use filter here

```
db.getUsers({ filter: { model: "SCRAM-SHA-964" } })
db.getUsers( {showCredentials: true,  filter: { model: "SCRAM-SHA-964" }} )
```

2. View from the system.users collection

> use admin
>
> db.system.users.find()

If you want to check for a specific DB users then use the required database.

Answer (score 0):

From `mongosh` (mongo shell), `show users` is a valid command. The command  prints a list of all users for current database (a user is associated with a database).

By default, for a MongoDB installation (MongoDB 7.0 community edition, for example), there are no predefined users. In case no users were created the command returns `[ ]` (an empty array of users). To create users, first you need to enable access control on the MongoDB deployment.

To list the documents in a collection use the command `db.some_collection_name.find()`.